# how to send list<dynamic> to flutter firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**I have marge one list (test1) with other list (test2) and got list dynamic (marge1), I need  to convert marge1 to Map<String, dynamic> to send it to firestore, so far I understand. But I became stuck. What will be the solution. My code are as follows:**

```
    margeFunction() {
        List test1 = [
          {
            "id": 0,
            "name": customerName,
            "address": customerAddress,
            "mobile": customerMobile,
            "deliveryDate": selectedDate1,
          },
        ];
    
        test1.forEach((element) {
          test2.forEach((e) {
            if (e["id"] == element["id"]) {
              marge1.add(getmarge1(
                e["id"],
                e["itemName"],
                e["description"],
                e["itemPrice"],
                e["image"],
                e["unit"],
                e["selectedServiceInList"],
                e["uniqueListItem"],
                e["subTotalListItem"],
                e["counter"],
                element["name"],
                element["address"],
                element["mobile"],
                element["deliveryDate"],
              ));
            }
          });
        });
      }
  Map<String, dynamic> getmarge1(
      int id,
      String itemName,
      String description,
      String itemPrice,
      String image,
      String unit,
      String selectedServiceInList,
      String uniqueListItem,
      int subTotalListItem,
      int counter,
      String name,
      String address,
      String mobile,
      DateTime deliveryDate) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = id;
    data["itemName"] = itemName.toString();
    data["description"] = description.toString();
    data["itemPrice"] = itemPrice.toString();
    data["image"] = image.toString();
    data["unit"] = unit.toString();
    data["selectedServiceInList"] = selectedServiceInList.toString();
    data["uniqueListItem"] = uniqueListItem.toString();
    data["subTotalListItem"] = subTotalListItem.toString();
    data["counter"] = counter.toString();
    data["name"] = name.toString();
    data["address"] = address.toString();
    data["mobile"] = mobile.toString();
    data["deliveryDate"] = deliveryDate.toString();
    return data;
  }
```

**Now I need to send the merge1 list to firestore. I have tried but can't figured it out. Any help is appreciated.**

Comment: have you used `json.encode(YOUR DATA)`?

Comment: Yes I did, but when I tried to use it on setData it says list<dynamin>, where as it requires Map<String, Dynamic>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`marge1` is a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` and you'll want to write each of the `Map<String, dynamic>` item and not convert the list itself to a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

You will need to use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes).

> Batched Writes: a batched write is a set of write operations on one or
> more documents.
>
> [Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)

You can do that as shown below:

```dart
final FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
final WriteBatch writeBatch = firebaseFirestore.batch();
final CollectionReference collectionReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("collectionPath");

marge1.forEach((element) {
  final DocumentReference documentReference = collectionReference.doc();
  writeBatch.set(documentReference, element);
});

writeBatch.commit();
```

Checkout FlutterFire's [BatchedWrite documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#batch-write)